# Converting List to Float

Tags: python, sql

After a SQL Query my code is returning:
[{'AVG (FTHG)': 1.0909090909090908}]

how do you get the float out of the containers it's in?, so it would just read:
1.0909090909090908

Comment: Do you mean, how do you get the float out of the containers it's in (which looks like a dictionary inside a list)? or do you mean, how do you round a float to two decimal places?

Comment: It seems to be already a float. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is `[{'AVG (FTHG)': 1.0909090909090908}]` a textual string, or do you mean that data structure? In the later case, maybe result[0]['AVG (FTHG)'] is what you're after? - actually, I just noticed that's basically what @Wasif Hasan in saying in the second part of his answer. Let us know what you want if we're to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use `round()`:

```
number = 1.09283293281
print(round(number, 2))
```

To get from list:

```
lst[0]['AVG (FTHG)']
```